# TERADATA: Numeric overflow occurred during computation в LEAST

Tags: sql, teradata

Столкнулся с проблемой переполнения при получении минимума:

> Error: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 13.10.00.01] [Error 2616] [SQLState 22003] Numeric overflow occurred during computation.
> SQLState:  22003
> ErrorCode: 2616

```
select 
        cast(252 as decimal(18,6)) as one
    ,cast(9602250000.000000 as decimal(18,6)) as two
    ,least(one, two) as resultLeastOne
    
    ,least(cast(252 as decimal(18,6)), cast(9602250000.000000 as decimal(18,6))) as resultLeastTwo
    
    ,least(252, 9602250000.000000) as resultLeastThree
```

Не могу понять что не нравится, вроде все сходится с [описанием](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#greatest-and-least)

Comment: Попробовал на http://tunweb.teradata.ws/SQLAssistantWeb/login.aspx?isTrial=1 (удалив `from V_DUAL`) - выполнилось нормально.

Comment: Тогда это еще более непонятно, так как прочитал официальную доку и не нашел чего либо странного... все должно выполняться...

Comment: Попробуйте запрос только с первым выражением, потом с первым и вторым... и так далее. Хотя бы понять, какой кусок серверу не нравится.

Comment: У меня тоже выполнилось в WEBе, на серверах компании никак...

Comment: Каждый кусок не работает, ни с вынесенными полями ни последующие два

Comment: А тупенькое `select 252 from V_DUAL` хотя бы - работает? Мне вот как раз активно это самое `from V_DUAL` глаз режет. Это что за таблица-то?

Comment: @Akina, V_DUAL - это псевдо таблица, на нее можно не обращать внимание, но чтобы было более понятно, без нее результат такой же. Проведя несколько тестов пришел к выводу, что на тестовом сервере компании указанный мною пример работает, а на боевом нет. Задал вопрос нашим админам. Как только появятся новости, обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: *V_DUAL - это псевдо таблица* Хмм... документация про неё что-то не в курсе... а псевдотаблица `DUAL` так и вовсе *The synthetic DUAL table is no longer supported.* согласно Release Notes к 0.70...

Answer (score 0):

В итоге рабочий вариант выглядит так:

```
    select 
             cast(252 as decimal(18,6)) as one
            ,cast(9602250000.000000 as decimal(18,6)) as two
            ,td_sysfnlib.least(one, two) as resultLeastOne
            ,td_sysfnlib.least(cast(252 as decimal(18,6)), cast(9602250000.000000 as decimal(18,6))) as resultLeastTwo
            ,td_sysfnlib.least(252, 9602250000.000000) as resultLeastThree
```

необходимо уточнять системную библиотеку для функций: td_sysfnlib
Видимо наши админы написали аналог.